# Ayuda con un programa de matrices en C++

Tags: c++, matrices

El problema es que no se como contar los números de una `matriz[5][7]`, necesito saber quien fue el alumno que reprobó mas materias, la matriz es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int main() {
    int matriz[5][7] = {
      { 9, 7, 6, 8, 9, 7 },
      { 10, 10, 6, 8, 9, 9 },
      { 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6 },
      { 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 9 },
      { 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10 }
    };
    int i=0, j=0, cont=0;

    printf("La matriz que usted ingreso:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            printf("%d,", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    std::map< int, int > contadorRepeticiones;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            contadorRepeticiones[matriz[i][j]]++;           
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Seria de gran ayuda si me dijeran como puedo hacerlo.
Saludos.

Comment: Cual es la condición para que repruebes una materia?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres por "contar los números"?

Comment: ¿Qué significa reprobar?

Comment: Que la calificacion sea menos a 7, por ejemplo el alumno que mas reprobo es el quinto, que tiene cuatro 6, y quiero que me indique que ese es el alumno con mas materias reprobadas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suponiendo que cada fila son las notas de un alumno, primeramente la matriz es de dimensión [5][6]

```
int main()
{
    int matriz[5][6] = {
        { 9, 7, 6, 8, 9, 7 },
        { 10, 10, 6, 8, 9, 9 },
        { 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6 },
        { 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 9 },
        { 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10 }
    };
    int i=0, j=0;

    printf("La matriz que usted ingreso:");
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            printf("%d,", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int matrizrepro[5];   //MATRIZ QUE GUARDA EL NUMERO DE MATERIAS REPROBADAS POR CADA ALUMNO
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int contadorMateria = 0;
        for(j = 0;j < 6;j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] < 7){
                contadorMateria++;
            }
        }
        matrizrepro[i] = contadorMateria; //GUARDA EL NUMERO DE MATERIAS REPROBADAS
        printf("Alumno %d tiene %d materias Reprobadas \n", i+1, contadorMateria);
    }

    //DETERMINA EL ALUMNO QUE TIENE MAS MATERIAS REPROBADAS
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int contadorMayor = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            if(matrizrepro[i] > matrizrepro[j] || matrizrepro[i] == matrizrepro[j]){
                    contadorMayor++;
            }
        }
        if(contadorMayor == 5){
             printf("Alumno %d es el que más materias ha reprobado con %d materias",i+1, matrizrepro[i]);
             break; // CUANDO ENTRA EN ESTA CONDICION ES EL NUMERO MAYOR Y YA NO HACE FALTA BUSCAR MAS
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Para este ejemplo la respuesta sería la siguiente:

> Alumno 1 tiene 1 materias Reprobadas
>   Alumno 2 tiene 1 materias Reprobadas
>   Alumno 3 tiene 1 materias Reprobadas
>   Alumno 4 tiene 2 materias Reprobadas
>   Alumno 5 tiene 4 materias Reprobadas

Y Aquí se imprime el alumno que tiene mas materias reprobadas:

> Alumno 5 es el que más materias ha reprobado con 4 materias

Comment: Muchas gracias.